# Resize background image to window size with Tkinter grid manager

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know how to resize the background image to the window size with the tkinter grid manager. My image is resizing alone, without resizing the window. It functions with the pack manager but I want to use it with the grid manager.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("800x600")

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.image = Image.open("courbe.gif")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.grid(row =0, column =0,sticky="nsew")
        self.background.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.background.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

e = Example(root)
e.grid(row =0, column =0,sticky="nsew")
e.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
e.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't bind to the background changing, but the window (`master`) changing. Then you can get the new height and width of the window using `master.winfo_width()` and `master.winfo_height()`.

So in your `__init__` use

```
self.master = master
self.master.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)
```

and in your `self._resize_image` use

```
new_width = self.master.winfo_width()
new_height = self.master.winfo_height()
```